# Android: BroadcastReceiver onReceive Callback not Triggered

Tags: android, callback, broadcastreceiver, wifi

I am writing a simple activity that programmatically joins a WiFi network. Here is my code:

```
public class WiFiSettings extends AppCompatActivity
{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wi_fi_settings);

    WifiManager oWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    configure(oWifiManager, "my-wifi", "1234", "WPA");//wrote this method myself. I know that it works. The phone is able to join the network.

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
    Poop bigone = new Poop();
    registerReceiver(bigone, intentFilter);
}

private class Poop extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("it worked", "!");
    }
}


}
```

Why is the onReceive method not being called back? The configure method works and is able to successfully join a given network, but upon joining or failing to join a network, the onReceive method doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by changing the intent filter...

```
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
```